# Javascript Prototype + HTML rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Noobie here: I'm trying to create a prototype for a dice (6 sides), with each dice object storing it's current value (the current face value) and a HTML-corresponded representation. What I would like is to have the representation and values both update when rolling the dice.

I have the three following functions that I'm having trouble implementing:

```
function rollD(){
  this.val = randomInt(1,6) //random integer function to choose between 1 - 6
  this.icons = ; //dice icons

}


rollD.prototype.render = function(){
     //how does HTMY rendering work?
   }


rollD.prototype.roll(){
```

//roll dice incorporating jQuery
        }

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how to update the image and how the rendering works and would like to learn Javascript OOP, so no short cuts would be great. Thank you

Comment: Do you want an animation, with asynchronous result for your `roll` method?

Comment: You don't need to use prototype here and you can combine all three functions into one.

Comment: @Bergi no animation is needed. thank you for replying

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when programming dice is so common? Here's just one way of doing it: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/dice.shtml

Comment: @slime likely to learn, as he said he was a newbie

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.rollDice = function () {
        // `dice` array
        var dice = ["\u2680"
                    , "\u2681"
                    , "\u2682"
                    , "\u2683"
                    , "\u2684"
                    , "\u2685"];
        // return _two_ `dice` items,
        // remove `+ dice[
        // 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * dice.length - 1)
        // ]` , to return _one_ die
        // `1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * dice.length - 1)
        // ]` returns "pseudo" random number,
        // utilized to reference an `index` within `dice` array
        return $(this).text(dice[
            1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * dice.length - 1)
        ] + dice[
            1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * dice.length - 1)
        ])
    }
}(jQuery));

// call `$.fn.rollDice` on `.dice` selector 
$(".dice").rollDice();
```

```js
(function ($) {
    $.fn.rollDice = function () {
        var dice = ["\u2680"
                    , "\u2681"
                    , "\u2682"
                    , "\u2683"
                    , "\u2684"
                    , "\u2685"];
        return $(this).text(dice[
            1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * dice.length - 1)
        ] + dice[
            1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * dice.length - 1)
        ])
    }
}(jQuery));
    
    

$(".dice").rollDice()
```

```css
.dice {
    font-size:72px;
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dice"></div>
```

Comment: Woulld you mind providing explanation for some steps? thank you

Comment: @SumYungGai See https://api.jquery.com/text/ , http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: I dont think they were asking at all how to "create a jquery plugin" I think they wanted to learn JavaScript Object Oriented Notation, and they are just creating a dice game as an example to help learn OOP, your example does what they asked for but does not help them learn what they actually wanted to learn.

Comment: @DustinPoissant yes, that is my goal. thank you. I appreciate all who answered, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can create methods for a prototype by accessing the `this` keyword within the constructor (function). I would only recomment using the `prototype` member for modifying already created (native) prototypes such as Array, String, or Math (math uses `__proto__` instead of `prototype`)

I created a quick dice example here: (this example uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com))

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emyjpz

**HTML**

```
<button id='d1' class='dice'>ROLE ME</button>
<button id='d2' class='dice'>ROLE ME</button>
<button id='d3' class='dice'>ROLE ME</button>
<button id='d4' class='dice'>ROLE ME</button>
<button id='d5' class='dice'>ROLE ME</button>
<br>
<button onclick='$(".dice").trigger("click");'>Roll All</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.dice {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: transparent;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 16px;
}
```

**JavaScript** (with jQuery)

```
Math.randInt = function(min, max){
  return Math.floor((Math.random()*((max+1)-min))+min);
}
function Dice(htmlID){
  this.id = htmlID;
  this.value = false;
  this.roll = function(){
    this.value = Math.randInt(1,6);
    $("#"+this.id).html(this.value);
  }
  $("#"+this.id).on("click",this.roll);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  new Dice("d1");
  new Dice("d2");
  new Dice("d3");
  new Dice("d4");
  new Dice("d5");
});
```

---

### Edit: Using .prototype

This is the same example but it uses the `prototype` member.

http://codepen.io/dustinpoissant/pen/KwZBGN

**JavaScript** (with jQuery)

```
Math.randInt = function(min, max){
  return Math.floor((Math.random()*((max+1)-min))+min);
}
function Dice(htmlID){
  this.id = htmlID;
  this.value = false;
  $("#"+this.id).on("click",this.roll);
}
Dice.prototype.roll = function(){
    this.value = Math.randInt(1,6);
    $("#"+this.id).html(this.value);
  }
$(document).ready(function(){
  new Dice("d1");
  new Dice("d2");
  new Dice("d3");
  new Dice("d4");
  new Dice("d5");
});
```

Hope this clears things up a little.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Would you mind showing me how to modify each prototype? I'm trying to learn OOP and would like to gain a better understanding of each step. Thank you.

Comment: Your right __proto__ is unessisary. I'll fix the example.