# Clicking on Dice won't work (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to initialize a die and roll it based on a click. This is what I have come up with so far. It works when I call roll in the console, but it won't work when I click.

```
function Dice() {
    this.die = randInt(0,5);
    this.icons = "⚀⚁⚂⚃⚄⚅";
    this.el = "<d6>" + this.icons.charAt(this.die) + "</d6>";
}

Dice.prototype.render = function() {
    $( "d6" ).remove();
    $("body").append(this.el);

}

Dice.prototype.roll = function() {
    this.die = randInt(0,5);
    this.el = "<d6>" + this.icons.charAt(this.die) + "</d6>";
   this.render();
}
```

Here is my click function that I've been trying out. Any help?

```
var dice = this;
$("this.el").click(function(){
     dice.roll();
});
```

Comment: take `this.el` out of quotes: `$(this.el).click(function(){dice.role});`

Comment: umm... how is this being displayed?

Comment: What is Dice.render()?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460760/javascript-prototype-html-rendering/

Comment: i've added edits but it still wont work

Comment: what are you clicking? where's that source code?

Comment: @Ted [link](http://postimg.org/image/jig2ya8zj/). i'm trying to click that but it wont roll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of problems with what you have there:

- You have a syntax error after the `Dice()` constructor (a stray `);`).
- `$("this.el")` makes no sense, and even if you use `$(this.el).click()`, the `$(this.el)` will actually be *creating* a new element (because `this.el` is an HTML string) instead of selecting the one that you added to your page.

The remedy to the first bullet is self-evident. To remedy the second, I've modified the place where you assign to `this.el` to create the element there on the spot.

The following should work:

```js
function randInt(min, max) {
    return ~~(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}    

function Dice() {
    this.die = randInt(0,5);
    this.icons = "⚀⚁⚂⚃⚄⚅";
}

Dice.prototype.render = function() {
    $( "d6" ).remove();
    $("body").append(this.el);
    var dice = this;
    console.log(this.el);
    this.el.click(function(){
        dice.roll();
    });
}

Dice.prototype.roll = function() {
    this.die = randInt(0,5);
    this.el = $("<d6>" + this.icons.charAt(this.die) + "</d6>");
    this.render();
}

var d = new  Dice();
d.roll();
```

```css
d6 {
    font-size: 600%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```